# Triangle Adjacency for shadow volume on flat Mesh

Tags: opengl, shadow

I'm trying to implement a shadow volume system but I'm thinking about a problem.
I'm using flat mesh to represent my world but how does triangle adjacency work for such object ?

I mean for the ledge vertices, It can't get the vertices from other object, so maybe using shadow volume isn't the best approach for my problem ? I already tried shadow map and the result got a low quality so if shadow volume isn't the solution what could it be ?

Comment: Do you mean how to get the silhouette edges?

Comment: I mean when I have a "2D" terrain with height making it 3D, but it's still like a quad with a lot of vertices, what would be the adjacency of the ledge vertices ?

Comment: I don't understand what "ledge vertices" means

Comment: Oh sorry, when I traduce that in my langage it make sense, I mean the vertices from the side of my mesh. (Which is like a quad)